# Containing block of an absolutely positioned element without "top", "right", "bottom" or "left"

Tags: css, position, css-position

I remember reading somewhere, a long time ago, that absolutely positioning an element withoout giving it any `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` property will (as any positioned element) take it out of the flow, but keep it inside the same containing block (the one it's supposed to be in when statically positioned).

On the example below ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukEh4/)), elements #2 and #3 are absolutely positioned, but #2 hasn't any additional properties.

[image]

I've been looking for documentation explaining that behavior so that I could continue using this without fearing for possible backslashes, but haven't been lucky on Gooogle or SO. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: this might help: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: It didn't, they're only talking about "basic" positioning techniques

Comment: you haven't used absolution position anywhere in your code :/

Comment: @Mr_Green I put it inline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For absolutely positioned elements, the default values for the offsets (`top`, `left` and so on) are `auto`.

In this case, the element remains in the position it would have it had `position: static` even though the content is taken out of the document flow.

References to the 'static position' concept include:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props

To quote:

> **10.3.7 Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements**
>
> For the purposes of this section and the next, the term "static position" (of an element) refers, roughly, to the position an element would have had in the normal flow. More precisely:
>
> The static-position containing block is the containing block of a hypothetical box that would have been the first box of the element if its specified 'position' value had been 'static' and its specified 'float' had been 'none'.

Answer (score 2):

It won't keep it inside the containing block, as once it's absolutely positioned it's always outside of the document flow. What it does do (without setting top/bottom/left/right) is keep it in the default position it would have been if it was still position static.

To force it to be inside the parent container, set the parent as position: relative and the top/bottom/left/right as needed.

Comment: I'll accept @Marc's answer since it links to doc, but thanks for the additional help. 

Agreed it's out of the flow, but since it's in the same position it would have been if it was static, it's visually inside the same containing block, and always will be. (Or can you think of any case it wouldn't?)

Comment: Note that if a parent container has `position: {relative | absolute | fixed}`, then any absolutely positioned child element will be positioned with respect to the parent block.